# Change the Image(image url) of ButtonField which is added in Gridview by onclick event

Tags: asp.net

I add a ButtonField in one Gridview's Column so there is Buttonfield for each Record as below code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvDetail" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Img/Black.png" CommandName="ggg" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In this i wants to change the image(image url) by clicking on that Button field..

**I add a column STATUS in the Gridview...**

I wants to change the image of Buttonfield 4 times..

it means default it displays the "black image" and STATUS is "1" 
on 1st click it changes to "blue image" and STATUS must be changed to "2" 
on 2nd click it changes to "green image" STATUS "3"
 on 3rd click it changes to "red image" STATUS "4". 
and on 4th click again it changes to "black image" STATUS "1"..

Its also working like on 1st click it change the image from black to blue and STATUS from "1" to "2" 
but when again i click on that it does not work.. to change it again. it needs to stop the project from running. and rerun it. then it works for only one click then again needs to stop the project and so on... 
Any Solution for this????

My code is as below..

protected void GvDetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

if (e.CommandName=="ggg")
        {

```
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        int temp;
        temp = Convert.ToInt32(GvDetail.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text);
      // gets the ID of clicked row from First Column(Name="Id")

        com = new SqlCommand();
        var _with1 = com;
        _with1.Connection = con;


        if (GvDetail.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text == "1")
        {
            string str1;
            str1 = "update SubTask set Status='2' where ID= '" + temp + "'";
            _with1.CommandText = str1;
            Label4.Text = "Start";
            Label4.Text = str1;

            GridViewRow gvRow = GvDetail.Rows[index];
            ((ImageButton)gvRow.Controls[0].Controls[0]).ImageUrl = "~/Image/Green.png";
        }

        else if (GvDetail.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text == "2")
        {
            string str1;
            str1 = "update SubTask set Status='3' where ID= '" + temp + "'";
            _with1.CommandText = str1;
            Label4.Text = "Start";
            Label4.Text = str1;
            GridViewRow gvRow = GvDetail.Rows[index];
            ((ImageButton)gvRow.Controls[0].Controls[0]).ImageUrl = "~/Image/Blue.png";
        }

        else if (GvDetail.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text == "3")
        {
            string str1;
            str1 = "update SubTask set Status='4' where ID= '" + temp + "'";
            _with1.CommandText = str1;
            Label4.Text = "Start";
            Label4.Text = str1;
            GridViewRow gvRow = GvDetail.Rows[index];
            ((ImageButton)gvRow.Controls[0].Controls[0]).ImageUrl = "~/Image/Red.png";
        }

        else if (GvDetail.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text == "4")
        {
            string str1;
            str1 = "update SubTask set Status='1' where ID= '" + temp + "'";
            _with1.CommandText = str1;
            Label4.Text = "Start";
            Label4.Text = str1;
            GridViewRow gvRow = GvDetail.Rows[index];
            ((ImageButton)gvRow.Controls[0].Controls[0]).ImageUrl = "~/Image/Black.png";
        }

        _with1.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }


}
```

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add command :

[image]

bind data

[image]

write code for command

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1j0Q.png
[image]

press

[image]

[image]

P.S. you could have used findcontrol

but since your gridview is not within a template -

so it doesn't have an Id

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks..
Your code is working..
but i have a problem read my question again coz i edit that..

Comment: @stranger - if royi has helped - then i would mark that as an answer and raise a separate question. Royi has obviously put work in here and i think deserves it - also your new question will get more interest and more contributors. Just MHO of course

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a handler to the `RowCommand` event. In it you can find which button was clicked from the `GridViewCommandEventArgs` (CommandSource I think) and the change the url to the image.