# On row editing event get current values from tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a table called me : with 3 columns: `Name`,`SecName`,`Code`

```
 void GridView1_RowEditing(Object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
    name = "";
    subname = "";
    code = "";
 }
```

How can I get the name,subname,code from selected row into those variables.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that you have on page?

Comment: look at my detailed answer  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140930/change-the-imageimage-url-of-buttonfield-which-is-added-in-gridview-by-onclick/9141097#9141097

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get the currently bound item by doing:

```
((ObjectBoundToGridRow)e.Item.DataItem).<X>
```

So you can extract it from the source object, but you can also do:

```
string name = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(e.Item.DataItem, "Name");
```

HTH.

Comment: what shall I do with this : ((ObjectBoundToGridRow)e.Item.DataItem).<X>

Comment: e.Item.DataItem refers to the object bound to the edited item... what are you binding, a class or data row?  Cast e.Item.DataItem to the object being bound to the row, and get the name directly from the data value.

Comment: Then let's take a step back.  How are you binding the grid?  What are you binding it to?  I need to see that before we can go any further...

Comment: I'm using : sqlconnection connection,sql parameters .

Comment: Are you binding it to a DataTable using Sqldataadapter, or using a sqldatareader?

Comment: bind what? there's no bind method used .

Comment: simple question.. do you see data on the gridview when you ran your code? if so where is that data comming from? you have to bind it in order for the data to show up on gridview.

Comment: @DanCristian As in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx or also accessing the object like this: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_23496451.html (scroll to the bottom, one of the posts has an example).

Comment: Yes I can see the data on gridview when I Run the code , and the code is coming from sqldatabase source . I still couldn't find a solution .ty